# Why the div tag innerHTML attribute doesn't change when I assigned it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I am writing a JavaScript function, named increment(), where the content of the content inside the div is going to show how many times the user has pressed the submit button in the form. But my JavaScript function doesn't work:

```
let div_content = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML; 

function increment(){
  counter++;  
  div_content = counter;
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form onsubmit="increment(); return false;">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn">
  </form>  
  <div id = "d">
    0
  </div>
```

I've changed the JS code and it worked, but I couldn't understand why it worked when I removed the variable div_content.

```
let counter = 0;
function increment(){
  counter++;
  document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = counter;

}
```

**UPDATE**:

Thank you for your help. I finally could understand what happened:
This line of code
`div_content = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML;`
creates a string variable instead of an object. That's why the content inside the div tag didn't change.

The correct JavaScript code must be:

```
let counter = 0;
const div_content = document.getElementById('d'); 

function increment(){
  counter++;  
  div_content.innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Comment: it should be `div_content.innerHtml = counter`

Comment: `innerHtml` is not a valid property. Try out [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: *Always* check the error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've changed the JS code and it worked, but I couldn't understand why
> it worked when I removed the variable div_content.

Your `div_content` was just a static string according to your definition:

```
let div_content = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML;
```

This just assigns the value of `innerHTML` at that time to the variable `div_content`. It is now totally unrelated to the element in any way. So changing that string to `counter` would change the string, yet not the content of `#d`:

```
div_content = counter; //REM: Assuming div was a typo
```

```js
let counter = 1;

//REM: div_content holds the string value of innerHTML at this time;
let div_content = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML;
console.log(div_content);

//REM: div_content now holds the value of counter
div_content = counter;
console.log(div_content);

//REM: Yet the innerHTML of #d never gets changed
```

```html
<div id = "d">0</div>
```

To actually change the `innerHTML` of `#d` you would have to assign the element to `div` and after update its property:

```
let div = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML;
div.innerHTML = counter;
```

```js
let counter = 1;

//REM: div holds a reference to the element #d
let div = document.getElementById('d');

//REM: The innerHTML of #d gets changed to the content of counter
div.innerHTML = counter;

//REM: This equals your final solution of 
document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = counter;
```

```html
<div id = "d">0</div>
```

Finally, combined, you would end up with something alike:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = increment;

//let div_content = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML; 
let div = document.getElementById('d'); 
let counter = 0;

function increment(){
  counter++;  
  //div = counter;
  div.innerHTML = counter;
}
```

```html
<button>inc</button>
<div id = "d">
  0
</div>
```

Please be aware of the drawbacks and security risks using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Answer (score 0):

In the first function u forget to name the variable right.

Yor code:

```
let div_content = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML; 

function increment(){
  counter++;  
  div = counter;
}
```

And the right code needs to be:

```
let div_content = document.getElementById('d').innerHTML; 

function increment(){
  counter++;  
  div_content = counter;
}
```